# ?Invalid char constant compile error ?cannot able to declare in java

Tags: java

I am trying declare char constant in java it throwing invalid constant error.

```
public static final char code = 'RETURN';
```

Comment: A char has to be a single character, I suspect you need a string

Answer (score 1):

A `char` represents a single character like `'C'`. To represent a word you need a String variable such as:

`public static final String code = "RETURN";`